# Postgres equivalent of MySQL's BENCHMARK() function

Tags: mysql, performance, postgresql, database-performance, postgresql-performance

I am using Postgresql. I want to test how much time a function takes to execute. Since the function takes only a few milliseconds, I would like to call it in a loop 1000s of times to get an accurate figure.

MySQL has a BENCHMARK() function to do this. Is there an equivalent or do I have to write a procedure with a loop to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you typically do this with `generate_series`:

```
SELECT my_function()
FROM generate_series(1,5000);
```

or

```
SELECT (SELECT my_query ....)
FROM generate_series(1,5000);
```

In the latter case you can add `OFFSET 0` to the subquery or wrap it in a `STRICT` SQL function to prevent the query planner from pulling out common conditions and subclauses and otherwise being clever.

Timing can be obtained with psql's `\timing` command, with `SET log_duration = on`, or with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`, all of which time subtly different things - see the documentation. In brief, `\timing` measures time including round-trips and value transfer to the client. `log_duration` measures server-side execution time. `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` measures details of the statement's execution but adds timing overhead that can slow it down a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Write a procedure with a loop - shouldn't take more than 5 minutes.

Comment: Did that already but it would be nice to know if there is a standard function.